# Apache Ignite - (jvm-pause-detector-worker) Possible too long JVM pause:

Tags: ignite

After using apache ignite 2.6, I am getting this warning constantly on JBoss start and stop. Could you please help me to know whats wrong configuration will lead this warnings.

Please let me know if you need any more details

Answer (score 9):

Most probably, JVM is experiencing long garbage collection pauses. You can configure detailed GC logs to see how much time is spent in GC: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/jvm-and-system-tuning#section-detailed-garbage-collection-stats

Try adding more heap to Ignite process or tuning the GC. Here is the documentation on GC tuning: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/jvm-and-system-tuning#garbage-collection-tuning