# Apache Ignite: Possible too long JVM pause: 714 milliseconds

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, garbage-collection, jvm, ignite

I have a setup of Apache Ignite server and having SpringBoot application as client in a Kubernetes cluster.

During performance test, I start to notice that the below log showing up frequently in SpringBoot application:

`org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal: Possible too long JVM pause: 714 milliseconds`

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52400019/apache-ignite-jvm-pause-detector-worker-possible-too-long-jvm-pause), this is due to "JVM is experiencing long garbage collection pauses", but Infrastructure team has confirmed to me that we have included `+UseG1GC` and `+DisableExplicitGC` in the Server JVM option and this line of log only show in SpringBoot application.

Please help on this following questions:

1. Is the GC happening in the Client(SpringBoot application) or Server node?
2. What will be that impact of long GC pause?
3. What should I do to prevent the impact?
4. Do I have to configure the JVM option in SpringBoot application as well?

Comment: First you need to confirm that the issue is caused by the garbage collector. Enable GC log and see if the GC pauses are really that big: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/jvm-and-system-tuning#section-detailed-garbage-collection-stats You can use https://gceasy.io/ website to visualize the logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Is the GC happening in the Client(SpringBoot application) or Server node?*

GC error will be logged to the log of the node which suffers problems.

*What will be that impact of long GC pause?*

Such pauses decreases overall performance. Also if pause will be longer than failureDetectionTimeout node will be disconnected from cluster.

*What should I do to prevent the impact?*

General advises are collected here - https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/jvm-and-system-tuning. Also you can enable GC logs to have full picture of what happens.

*Do I have to configure the JVM option in SpringBoot application as well?*

Looks like that you should, because you have problems with client's node.